# Doxygen ignores Words and Functions

Tags: doxygen, pascal

I have the following doxygen file:

```
/** @mainpage PConnect

@section s_definition Definition

This guide is the main documentation of Pascal/Delphi Connector Wrapper for the CGM Assist. 

@section s_definition Definition 
The PConnect gives you the ability to use the Connector of the CGM-Assist by using Pascal/Delphi      functions. 

@note For further information take a look into the "Implementation Guide"
*/
```

Now I try to generate this .dox file, but I always get this as Output:

```
Definition

This guide is the main documentation of /Delphi Connector Wrapper for the CGM Assist.

Definition

The PConnect gives you the ability to use the Connector of the CGM-Assist by using /Delphi . @ " "
```

Do you have an idea, why it always cut out the "Pascal"? And why it doesn't write the full content?

Another strange restrained is, that if I just write this:

```
{* @brief A simple Key/Value Record
*  @param key Key
*  @param value Value to the key
}
Map = record
  var key: PAnsiChar;
  var value: PAnsiChar;
end;
```

then it doesn't show the record in the documentation. But if I write another Record in front of this like:

```
    //Only if this record is written here, the "Map" will be shown in documentation xD
    Test = Record
      var test: PAnsiChar;
    end;

    {* @brief A simple Key/Value Record
    *  @param key Key
    *  @param value Value to the key
    }
    Map = record
      var key: PAnsiChar;
      var value: PAnsiChar;
    end;
```

Then it shows the Record "Map" in the documentation.

PS: I'm using pas2dox for the sourcecode documentation.

Comment: I find out, why it ignore that stuff.
If I write the pas2dox.exe into the "INPUT_FILTER" it cut the test. But I don't know how to solve my problem, because I have to use the pas2dox for the delphi documentation